# Get x range and print it of throw trajectory

Tags: plotting

here is code of my program

```
g := 9.81
p := 30
kat := p*(Pi/180) (* ok 45 stopni*)

(*    \
y=x*Tan[kat]-g/(2*vXpocz^2)*x^2   *)
Manipulate[
 Plot[x*Tan[p * (Pi/180)] - 
   g/(2*(Vstart*Sin[p * (Pi/180)])^2)*x^2, {x, 0, 700}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x [m], h [m]}, PlotLabel -> "Throw trajectory plot",
  PlotRange -> {0, 300}],

 {Vstart, 10, 50}, {p, 30, 60},
 Button["Print", {Print["Max height: ", 
    FindMaximum[
     x*Tan[p * (Pi/180)] - g/(2*(Vstart*Sin[p * (Pi/180)])^2)*x^2, {x,
       0, 700}]],
   Print["Range: ", Vstart^2/g*Sin[2*(p * (Pi/180))]]}
  ]]
```

And here is output

[image]

I want that my program will gave me height and range after clicking button.
It work but range value is't correct. Is there any function that check when there instersection on x axis ?

Comment: The problem is not the calculation of `range`, the problem is your plot: Notice the weird behaviour when you vary `p`- that doesn't seem like a proper inclined throw. You can fix this by replacing `Sin` with `Cos` in the argument to plot (the second term should be $-\frac g2 t^2=-\frac g2 \left(\frac x{v_x}\right)^2$ with $v_x=v\cos p$, *not* $v_x=v\sin p$)

Comment: @LukasLang oh I see now :D thank you